# Problema ao criar Array multidimensional com Jquery

Tags: jquery, array, array-multidimensional

Preciso criar um array dessa forma:

```
"M":["02328280006985",{"61","63"},],"NM":["02328280007876",{"62","64"}]}
```

mas está saindo dessa forma:

```
"M":["02328280006985",{"61":[],"62":[],"63":[],"64":[]},{"61":[],"62":[],"63":[],"64":[]}],"NM":["02328280006985",{"61":[],"62":[],"63":[],"64":[]}]}
```

Meu código é esse:

```
var var ds_rateio = {};
var teste = {};
$('select[name="insTipoRateio[]"] option:selected').each(function() {
if(typeof(ds_rateio[$(this).val()]) == 'undefined' || typeof(teste[$(this).attr("data-nf")]) == 'undefined'){
    ds_rateio[$(this).val()] = [];
    teste[$(this).attr("data-nf")] = [];
}
ds_rateio[$(this).val()].push($(this).attr("data-cnpj"));
$.each(ds_rateio, function(key1, value) {
    value.push(teste);
});
});
var ds_rateio = JSON.stringify(ds_rateio);
```

Meu Html:

```
<tr>
<td>
    <div>
        <select class="insTipoRateio" id="insTipoRateio" name="insTipoRateio[]">
            <option value="M" data-nf="61"data-cnpj="02328280007876">M</option>
        </select>
    </div>  
</td>
<td>
    <div>
        <select class="insTipoRateio" id="insTipoRateio" name="insTipoRateio[]">
            <option value="NM" data-nf="62"data-cnpj="02328280006985">NM</option>
        </select>
    </div>  
</td>
<td>
    <div>
        <select class="insTipoRateio" id="insTipoRateio" name="insTipoRateio[]">
            <option value="M" data-nf="63"data-cnpj="02328280007876">M</option>
        </select>
    </div>  
</td>
<td>
    <div>
        <select class="insTipoRateio" id="insTipoRateio" name="insTipoRateio[]">
            <option value="NM" data-nf="64"data-cnpj="02328280006985">NM</option>
        </select>
    </div>  
</td>
```

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: O ideal é incluir o html também para se conseguir testar diretamente aqui no site. Para além disso convêm explicar de onde vem os números e qual a regra para saber quais capturar.

Comment: Editado Isac. O que preciso é criar um array por tipo (M ou NM), cada tipo é um outro array de CNPJ (cnpj1, cnpj2) e cada CNPJ é outro array com Notas fiscais (61, 63), (62, 64)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pessoalmente acho que a sua abordagem ficou um pouco complicada, e prefiro mostrar outra forma de solucionar o mesmo, por um caminho mais simples.

Comecei por criar uma função que testa se uma propriedade existe num objeto e caso não exista, cria-a com um determinado valor. Depois para cada opção uso essa função para criar o valor e cnpj caso não existam. No fim basta adicionar o valor do atributo `nf` que fica completo.

Código:

```js
const ds_rateio = {};

const criaPropSeVazio = (obj, prop, valor) => { 
  if (!(prop in obj)){
    obj[prop] = valor;
  }
};

$('select[name="insTipoRateio[]"] option:selected').each(function() {
  let valor = $(this).val();
  criaPropSeVazio(ds_rateio, valor, {});
  
  let cnpj = $(this).data("cnpj");
  criaPropSeVazio(ds_rateio[valor], cnpj, []);

  let nf = $(this).data("nf");
  ds_rateio[valor][cnpj].push(nf);
});

console.log(ds_rateio);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
<td>
    <div>
        <select class="insTipoRateio" id="insTipoRateio" name="insTipoRateio[]">
            <option value="M" data-nf="61"data-cnpj="02328280007876">M</option>
        </select>
    </div>  
</td>
<td>
    <div>
        <select class="insTipoRateio" id="insTipoRateio" name="insTipoRateio[]">
            <option value="NM" data-nf="62"data-cnpj="02328280006985">NM</option>
        </select>
    </div>  
</td>
<td>
    <div>
        <select class="insTipoRateio" id="insTipoRateio" name="insTipoRateio[]">
            <option value="M" data-nf="63"data-cnpj="02328280007876">M</option>
        </select>
    </div>  
</td>
<td>
    <div>
        <select class="insTipoRateio" id="insTipoRateio" name="insTipoRateio[]">
            <option value="NM" data-nf="64"data-cnpj="02328280006985">NM</option>
        </select>
    </div>  
</td>
```

Comment: Perfeito, funcionando do jeito que preciso! Obrigado!